# Chrome extension: How to inject content script into image?

Tags: json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest

Simple Question: How can I inject my content script into all images?

```
"matches":["*://*.png", "*://*.jpg", "*://*.jpeg", "*://*.gif"],
```

This was my first try and I'm getting an error.

Comment: "Into an image"? Are you referring to the document that you see when you view an image in a tab?

Comment: yes exactly thats what i mean

Comment: Read the documentation of [match patterns](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns). The host part is required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Rob pointed out in the comments, you need to include the host part

```
"matches":["*://*/*.png", "*://*/*.jpg", "*://*/*.jpeg", "*://*/*.gif"],
```